# PyQt5 Preview different than Python output

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using QtDesigner on PyQt5, with Python 3.5.1.

To get to the point, I have created an interface with the QtDesigner application that looks perfect in the preview, but when I convert it to a python application with `pyuic5 -x <filename.ui> -o <output.py>` and open the generated Python application it looks different and some of the positioning is wrong.

The top image shown below is the preview, this is good and what I want the final application to look like, and the bottom is the actual application generated with the `pyuic5` command with the ugly whitespace.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this and make the final Python application to look exactly (or almost/close enough) to the preview that I designed?

[image: Preview Interface]
[image: Output Interface]

I have found nothing via the standard Google search, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the ui file, but I would guess that you are trying to position widgets manually, rather than using layouts.

Comment: @ekhumoro No, this was all done with the Designer application.

Comment: I know that you're using Qt designer. You need to use layouts. Don't try to size/position widgets using absolute values. Read the tutorial on [Using layouts in Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).